# When trying to use emmeans on mixedmodel object in Julia via Rcall, how to solve this methoderror (no matching Linearmixedmodel float64)

Tags: r, julia, mixed-models

```
# Take 'mme' from julia, convert to R, then use emmeans to get adjusted means
 using RCall
 R"library(emmeans)"
       R"library(lme4)"
       R"library(lmerTest)"

       # convert to R
       R"mme <- $(mme)"
```

I am trying to take 'mme' mixedmodel object from Julia and apply emmeans function via Rcall. But facing this errror.

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching sexpclass(::LinearMixedModel{Float64})
Closest candidates are:
  sexpclass(::FormulaTerm) at C:\Users\USER\.julia\packages\RCall\Wyd74\src\convert\default.jl:256
  sexpclass(::CategoricalArrays.CategoricalArray) at C:\Users\USER\.julia\packages\RCall\Wyd74\src\convert\default.jl:270
  sexpclass(::AbstractDict) at C:\Users\USER\.julia\packages\RCall\Wyd74\src\convert\default.jl:250
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] sexp(s::LinearMixedModel{Float64})
   @ RCall C:\Users\USER\.julia\packages\RCall\Wyd74\src\convert\default.jl:214
 [2] setindex!(e::Ptr{EnvSxp}, v::LinearMixedModel{Float64}, s::String)
   @ RCall C:\Users\USER\.julia\packages\RCall\Wyd74\src\methods.jl:553
 [3] top-level scope
   @ C:\Users\USER\.julia\packages\RCall\Wyd74\src\macros.jl:66
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RCall doesn't have built-in conversions for all possible Julia types, so you need to either define conversions for a given type or use a package that provides that conversion. For the case of converting types from the MixedModels.jl package, there is [JellyMe.jl](https://github.com/palday/JellyMe4.jl). From its docs, there is a usage example:

```
julia> using MixedModels, RCall, JellyMe4
julia> machines = rcopy(R"nlme::Machines")
54×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ Worker       │ Machine      │ score   │
│     │ Categorical… │ Categorical… │ Float64 │
├─────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1            │ A            │ 52.0    │
│ 2   │ 1            │ A            │ 52.8    │
│ 3   │ 1            │ A            │ 53.1    │
│ 4   │ 2            │ A            │ 51.8    │
│ 5   │ 2            │ A            │ 52.8    │
│ 6   │ 2            │ A            │ 53.1    │
⋮
│ 48  │ 4            │ C            │ 64.0    │
│ 49  │ 5            │ C            │ 72.1    │
│ 50  │ 5            │ C            │ 72.0    │
│ 51  │ 5            │ C            │ 71.1    │
│ 52  │ 6            │ C            │ 62.0    │
│ 53  │ 6            │ C            │ 61.4    │
│ 54  │ 6            │ C            │ 60.5    │

julia> m = fit(MixedModel, @formula(score ~ 1 + Machine + (1 + Machine|Worker)), machines)
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood
 score ~ 1 + Machine + (1 + Machine | Worker)
   logLik    -2 logLik      AIC         BIC
 -108.208914  216.417828  236.417828  256.307668

Variance components:
            Column     Variance   Std.Dev.   Corr.
Worker   (Intercept)  13.81760447 3.7172039
         Machine: B   28.68496515 5.3558347  0.49
         Machine: C   11.24097825 3.3527568 -0.36  0.30
Residual               0.92463436 0.9615791
 Number of obs: 54; levels of grouping factors: 6

  Fixed-effects parameters:
───────────────────────────────────────────────────
             Estimate  Std.Error   z value  P(>|z|)
───────────────────────────────────────────────────
(Intercept)  52.3556     1.53437  34.1218    <1e-99
Machine: B    7.96667    2.20988   3.60502   0.0003
Machine: C   13.9167     1.40579   9.89956   <1e-22
───────────────────────────────────────────────────
julia> # LinearMixedModel doesn't keep of the original dataframe,
julia> # so we need to package it up
julia> m_machines = (m, machines);
julia> @rput m_machines;
julia> R"summary(m_machines)"
RObject{VecSxp}
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid
   236.4    256.3   -108.2    216.4       44

Scaled residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max
-2.40773 -0.51890  0.03227  0.45598  2.54091

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 Worker   (Intercept) 13.8176  3.7172
          MachineB    28.6850  5.3558    0.49
          MachineC    11.2410  3.3528   -0.36  0.30
 Residual              0.9246  0.9616
Number of obs: 54, groups:  Worker, 6

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   52.356      1.534  34.122
MachineB       7.967      2.210   3.605
MachineC      13.917      1.406   9.900

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
         (Intr) MachnB
MachineB  0.463
MachineC -0.374  0.301
```

But if your main concern is computing estimated marginal means, then the [Effects.jl](https://github.com/beacon-biosignals/Effects.jl) package provides [support for doing so](https://beacon-biosignals.github.io/Effects.jl/stable/emmeans/).

Comment: Thanks. I tried emmeans first but it returned error. ERROR: UndefVarError: emmeans not defined. Hence, the other route. I will check with jellyme and let you know

Comment: So, Jellyme works but returns this error as their repo says.                                        ERROR: REvalError: Warning in optwrap(optimizer, devfun, getStart(start, rho$pp), lower = rho$lower,  :
  convergence code 5 from nloptwrap: NLOPT_MAXEVAL_REACHED: Optimization stopped because maxeval (above) was reached.

Comment: Effects.jl is the solution. Mine was not updated earlier. Now works fine. v 1.0.0